# Most elegant way to write a piece of code that handles ramping up and down?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have the following code in my microcontroller project:

```
if (newThrottle < currentThrottle)
{
    for (int set = currentThrottle; set >= newThrottle; set--)
    {
        // Perform actions to set the throttle
    }
}
else
{
    for (int set = currentThrottle; set <= newThrottle; set++)
    {
        // Perform actions to set the throttle
    }
}
```

If it's not blatantly obvious, this code snippet is used to ramp the motor throttle up or down from its current value to a new value.

Is there any more elegant way to write this?

Comment: Put the `actions to set the throttle` in a function, perhaps?

Comment: It's one two lines of code, I'd rather just put it in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int add = (newThrottle > currentThrottle) ? 1 : -1;

while (newThrottle != currentThrottle)
{
    // do your stuff
    currentThrottle += add;
}
```

Comment: Wow you guys are fast. I only just noticed that.

Comment: Hmm.. the only issue that I am having is that it doesn't seem to ever get down to zero. For example, if I ask it to ramp up to 40 then later back down again to 0, it doesn't seem to ever hit 0. any ideas?

Comment: @chris: See this: http://ideone.com/lU3mP. You'd have to set the `newThrottle = -1` to have the body of the loop executed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider doing something like this:

```
int step = newThrottle < currentThrottle ? -1 : 1;

for (int set = currentThrottle; set != newThrottle; set += step)
{
    // perform actions to set the throttle
}
```

If you don't mind some code that's harder to decipher, you could consider something like this:

```
int step = (newThrottle < oldThrottle) - (newThrottle > oldThrottle);
```

I think I'd use the first version though -- at least IMO, it's easier to read and understand. The second also depends on `true` converting to `1` and `false` converting to `0`.